# EasyPHP-Devserver 17: impossible to change MYSQL Data directory?

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I use easyPHP-DevServer 17 with mysql5.717, php 7.13 und phpmyadmin4.70 (it was like this in a bundle) under windows 10.
Since two days I try to configure EasyPHPDevserver as I would like to have it.
I want to store data on the data partition of my computer not on the system partition C:  I stopped all servers and the application EasyPHP-DevServer. I changed the data directory in the file mysql.ini, in the my-default.ini and the my.ini-bak file. 
If I run the application there is once again the old path in the ini-file and I get only the data base of the old data base source not of the new data base. I searched in the registry whithout finding any registry entry giving the data directory. How does it know the old directory?
Why doesn't it change?

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Thommy7571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the file `eds-app-action.php` in your MySQL folder.

- Find the line `// Update datadir`
- On the next line, replace `__DIR__` by your path (you can change `/data/` as well)

OR, easier

Comment the two next lines (`//$replacement...` and `//$serverconffile`) and edit the `my.ini` file as you did. Like this, your changes won't be erased.

Comment: Hello,                                                                                                                  Thanks very much. Works like a charme. I wouldn't have touched at the code normally but commenting is OK. I wonder why such lines have been added...      Thanks, Thommy7571

Comment: Thank you, but replacing __ DIR __  is very "dirty" (and I'm not sure to see what has to be edited), and commenting the two lines (as well as the other ones talking about data dir) does not work... And I wonder... Any enheanced idea ? What is the point of "datadir" in my.ini if it's always overriden and set to default ?